# Corner radius wrong - circular image looks like an eye

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm trying to make a circular image in Swift, I've searched around and watched a couple YouTube videos. The solutions proposed are extremely easy, but when I used them I get an image formed as an eye instead of a circle, below is my view controller and a picture of the UI

```
var experimentIdentifier: String = ""


@IBOutlet weak var foregroundImage: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    foregroundImage.layer.cornerRadius = (foregroundImage.frame.size.width) / 2
    foregroundImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

[image: Supposed to be a circular image]

Comment: Try to call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` before setting the corner radius.

Comment: is your image a square at first? using cornerRadius only works with a square view. You can add constraints to ensure your image is a square (set height and width) and adjust how it fits the frame with the contentMode attribute (Aspect fill for instance)

Comment: Make your image a square and use the image view's `contentMode` to control which part gets clipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's because your image is not a square.**

See this problem in action:

> Set the image to a width : height = 2 : 1 rectangle in storyboard

[image]

> then run, the image will look like

[image]

> but if the image is a square, like this in storyboard

[image]

> click run, it'll be like

[image]

Enjoy coding!

Answer (score 0):

**Try This ,**

```
        let profileImageView = UIImageView()
        profileImageView.frame = CGRectMake(150, 150, 60, 60)
        profileImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        profileImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        profileImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 60/2


        let image = UIImage(named: "yourImageName")
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.size.height/2
        profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image is not a square i guess. To make it square you have to make sure that height and width of the image are equals and then also add these two properties as well

```
foregroundImage.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * your image height 
foregroundImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
foregroundImage.clipsToBounds = true
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

make sure the image is a square then add this code

```
 foregroundImage.layer.cornerRadius = side/2
     foregroundImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
```